# Bringing up existing elements inside modal with Bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose I have a form with the form id = "form1":

```
<form id="form1">
   <input type="text">
</form>
```

I'm also displaying a button that allows the user to bring up a modal:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Click here to zoom in!
</button>
```

The challenge is that I want my modal to show the same form (form1), but so far I have not had much luck getting this. Below is my modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3>This is my header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

<!-- I WANT TO ADD THE INPUT FORM THAT EXISTS OUTSIDE THE MODAL HERE -->      

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

If the form and all this mark up is on the same page then put the form tag inside the div with class modal-body if that still does not work use java-script to show the modal. Here is sample working code,

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" id="showModalPopup" data-target="#myModal">
            Click here to zoom in!
        </button>

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">This is my header</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="form1">
                            <input type="text" />
                        </form> 

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#showModalPopup').on('click', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();         
           $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
       });
    });
    </script>
```

I hope it helps.